# MDX Query to Produce Revenue by Top N Advertiser

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to create a report using SSRS 2008 that will show the top 10 advertisers by revenue.  I wrote the MDX query in management studio as follows:

```
Select [Measures].[Value] on 0,
non empty
generate([Dim Industry].[SK Industry ID],
topcount([Dim Advertiser Branch].[Advertiser],
[Measures].[Value],bdesc),10)
on 1
from FuseCube
```

I get a parse error stating:

```
Query (5, 20) An expression was expected for the function argument and no expression   
was detected.
```

My goal is to report the top  10 Advertisers, their associated branch and industry by Value (aka revenue).  The remaining ranked advertisers should go into an "others" category so that I can sum the value and get a grand total.

How should I restructure the above MDX query to produce desired results?  Is it advisable to create the above query as a named set as it will be used repeatedly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOPCOUNT syntax incorrect:

```
topcount([Dim Advertiser Branch].[Advertiser], [Measures].[Value],bdesc),10)
```

Vs

```
TopCount([Dim Advertiser Branch].[Advertiser], 10, [Measures].[Value]))
```